# Google Maps Embed API Address Not Found

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed

I have embedded maps on each profile on my site. They all seem to work fine except for the one below. I'm not sure why, but when the map API loads, it's zoomed out so far you can see the whole world. Here is my `iframe` code with the query string:

```
<iframe width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAdGoEM5aW51rD_cyVwSBVrtAPZsEZruuQ&amp;q=177%20Huntington%20Ave.,Boston%20MA"></iframe>
```

Here is my API query string:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAdGoEM5aW51rD_cyVwSBVrtAPZsEZruuQ&amp;q=177%20Huntington%20Ave.,Boston%20MA
```

Now if I copy everything after `q=?` into the regular Google Maps site (see new query string below) it pulls up the correct location as expected. There aren't any errors in the console.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/177%20Huntington%20Ave.,Boston%20MA
```

I've tried adjusting the address by using the following street name and building number combinations below:

- 177 Huntington Ave.
- 177 Huntington Ave
- 177 Huntington Avenue

I've also tried adjusting the city/state using the combinations below:

- `address`, Boston MA
- `address` Boston MA
- `address`, Boston, MA
- `address` Boston, MA

Not sure what else I could try to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug. I [created a bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8344&thanks=8344&ts=1437090651) in gmaps-api-issues.

meanwhile, as a workaround, you can:

1) use center and zoom level to make sure that even if the Embed API fail, your user still see a map in that area.

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=177+Huntington+Avenue,+Boston,+MA,+United+States&center=42.3448913,-71.0829315&zoom=18&key=AIzaSyAdGoEM5aW51rD_cyVwSBVrtAPZsEZruuQ" allowfullscr
```

2) you can use the following code which is generated by the `maps.google.com`'s `Share or embed map` function:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2948.8889324642187!2d-71.0829315!3d42.3448913!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89e37a1052d49695%3A0xbdfe31a3b545364a!2s177+Huntington+Ave%2C+Boston%2C+MA+02115!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1437088598386" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug report. I also believe it's a bug. Hopefully it is resolved soon. I can't set the iframe src manually because the pages are managed via a CMS, but I might just put in 176 for the building number for now to get around the problem until a fix is released.